# Why is my apostrophe not showing correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm attempting to create a TextView with the text "You're offline", but I cannot figure out why it's messed up. The problem is the apostrophe. the design shows the apostrophe leaning to the right, but what I get is not. Since the string includes an apostrophe I have to have it escaped in my strings.xml. Not sure if that's related to the problem or not. Hard-coding the apostrophe in the layout XML displays incorrectly as well.

[image: problem example screenshot]

When I use the font in Word it shows as leaning right, so it only seems to be in Android that the font shows incorrectly.  Has anyone else seen this? How can I correct this? I found [this post](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/apostrophe.html) that might be related. I haven't been able to even find this character in the font, so it's baffling.

Answer (score 0):

This is the text with an apostrophe ( `<string name="message">You\&#39;are offline</string>`):

[image]

but if you what this character:

[image]

In yor `strings.xml` file you will use the html code for the "Spacing acute" that is :    `&#180;`, example:

```
<string name="message">You&#180;are offline</string>
```

then you will use the value to show the text with the apostrophe

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.message));
```

Comment: If I use the font in Microsoft Word, and type the apostrophe key (on my Mac that a key that has " and under it ', then it shows the character leaning to the right.  But when this same character appears in my TextView it looks like it is not leaning.  I assume the designer is using Adobe products to create the art comp I was given, because in the comp it's leaning to the right. So the same character appears leaning in Adobe Creative Suite and Word and NOT leaning in Android. I appreciate your response, but I don't want to force an acute accent, I want to understand why it's not showing correct.